# Multiline PHP script in Jade

Tags: php, html, pug

I'm building a website with Jade and PHP, and **I can't include multiline PHP scripts in my Jade file** because it throws an indent error.

This would be an example of my code:

```
        p.base Somos una empresa de distribución de Temped ea nos mi, sequam autecer spernat essimos dolorepud
        ul.grilla-productos-home 
            <?php
                $sql        = "SELECT a.IdProducto,a.NombreCorto,a.Descripcion as Descripcion,a.precioUnitario,a.Imagen,b.Descripcion as Categoria,c.Descripcion as SubCategoria FROM productos a, categoria b, subcategoria c WHERE a.IdCategoria=b.idCategoria AND a.IdSubCategoria=c.IdSubCategoria limit 12";
                $resultados = $pdo->query($sql);
                while ($registro = $resultados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<li class='producto'><ul class='producto-componentes'><li class='imagen-producto'><img src=" . $registro['Imagen'] . "alt='Sanitarios'/></li><li class='titulo-producto'>" . $registro["NombreCorto"] . "</li></li><li class='Material-producto'><p class='titulo-divisor-producto'>Material</p><p class='material-producto'>" . $registro['Descripcion'] . "</p></li><li class='precio-producto'>$" . $registro['precioUnitario'] . "</li><a href='detalle.php?Id=" . $registro['IdProducto'] . "'class='cta-ghost main'>Ver detalles</a> </ul></li>";
                }
            ?> 
            li.producto
```

When it tries to compile the code above, it throws this **error**:

```
unexpected token "indent"
```

Pointed at the second line of my script ("$sql...")

Due to this issue, **i'm forced to minify the scripts** to a single line, **which makes them really hard to edit** afterwards.

Is there a way I can include multiline inline scripts in a Jade template? Is there a better practice to make PHP scripts work in Jade?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just prefix your php as plain text

```
p.base Somos una empresa de distribución de Temped ea nos mi, sequam autecer spernat essimos dolorepud
  ul.grilla-productos-home  
  | <?php
  |              $sql        = "SELECT a.IdProducto,a.NombreCorto,a.Descripcion as Descripcion,a.precioUnitario,a.Imagen,b.Descripcion as Categoria,c.Descripcion as SubCategoria FROM productos a, categoria b, subcategoria c WHERE a.IdCategoria=b.idCategoria AND a.IdSubCategoria=c.IdSubCategoria limit 12";
  |              $resultados = $pdo->query($sql);
  |              while ($registro = $resultados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  |                echo "<li class='producto'><ul class='producto-componentes'><li class='imagen-producto'><img src=" . $registro['Imagen'] . "alt='Sanitarios'/></li><li class='titulo-producto'>" . $registro["NombreCorto"] . "</li></li><li class='Material-producto'><p class='titulo-divisor-producto'>Material</p><p class='material-producto'>" . $registro['Descripcion'] . "</p></li><li class='precio-producto'>$" . $registro['precioUnitario'] . "</li><a href='detalle.php?Id=" . $registro['IdProducto'] . "'class='cta-ghost main'>Ver detalles</a> </ul></li>";
  |              }
  |          ?> 
  li.producto
```

wich will produce

```
<p class="base">Somos una empresa de distribución de Temped ea nos mi, sequam autecer spernat essimos dolorepud
  <ul class="grilla-productos-home"> </ul><?php
               $sql        = "SELECT a.IdProducto,a.NombreCorto,a.Descripcion as Descripcion,a.precioUnitario,a.Imagen,b.Descripcion as Categoria,c.Descripcion as SubCategoria FROM productos a, categoria b, subcategoria c WHERE a.IdCategoria=b.idCategoria AND a.IdSubCategoria=c.IdSubCategoria limit 12";
               $resultados = $pdo->query($sql);
               while ($registro = $resultados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                 echo "<li class='producto'><ul class='producto-componentes'><li class='imagen-producto'><img src=" . $registro['Imagen'] . "alt='Sanitarios'/></li><li class='titulo-producto'>" . $registro["NombreCorto"] . "</li></li><li class='Material-producto'><p class='titulo-divisor-producto'>Material</p><p class='material-producto'>" . $registro['Descripcion'] . "</p></li><li class='precio-producto'>$" . $registro['precioUnitario'] . "</li><a href='detalle.php?Id=" . $registro['IdProducto'] . "'class='cta-ghost main'>Ver detalles</a> </ul></li>";
               }
           ?> 
  <li class="producto"></li>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this PHP fork of Jade: https://github.com/kylekatarnls/jade-php, you can do:

```
p.base Somos una empresa de distribución de Temped ea nos mi, sequam autecer spernat essimos dolorepud
  ul.grilla-productos-home
    - $sql        = "SELECT a.IdProducto,a.NombreCorto,a.Descripcion as Descripcion,a.precioUnitario,a.Imagen,b.Descripcion as Categoria,c.Descripcion as SubCategoria FROM productos a, categoria b, subcategoria c WHERE a.IdCategoria=b.idCategoria AND a.IdSubCategoria=c.IdSubCategoria limit 12"
    - $resultados = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    for registro in resultados
      li.producto: ul.producto-componentes
        li.imagen-producto
          img(src=registro.Imagen alt='Sanitarios')
      li.titulo-producto
        =registro.NombreCorto
      li.Material-producto:p.titulo-divisor-producto ...
```

But I recommand to do SQL requests in the controller, not in the view.